Is there a way to check whether an Android Drawable resource has a night variant?
We are using Glide in our app (but the question isn't specific to that), and it has issues with resolving dark/light mode resources as it uses the Application context to load resources. It will essentially just load the resource of the mode which was enabled when the resource is loaded for the first time and then cache and reuse that resource variant even if the theme changes.
To remedy that, we are setting a different ObjectKey/signature when loading while in light mode and another one when loading while in dark mode:
val signature = ObjectKey(drawableRes.toString() + if (isInDarkMode) "_dark" else "_light")

This signature is then used as a cache key.
This works, but isn't terribly efficient as we are obviously polluting the cache with 2 variants of each Drawable, although many Drawables only have light mode variants.
My idea to improve this was to check before loading and assigning the ObjectKey whether a resource actually has a night mode variant and only then use different keys. But I didn't find a way to do so at runtime.

"I could check the file system for such a variant" -- resources are not files on the device. They are only files on the development machine. On the device, they are entries in an APK file. "I hoped there was a more efficient way than doing file I/O" -- code-generate it based on what is on your development machine, using KotlinPoet and a custom Gradle task or plugin. "we are obviously polluting the cache with 2 variants of each Drawable" -- the code in the question does not do that, though it's possible you have other code not shown here that does.

Regarding cache pollution: if I use two different keys for one image, then I unfortunately do pollute the cache with unnecessary duplicates.

Regarding reading from file system: yes, you are obviously right @CommonsWare, updating the question accordingly.

Could you elaborate on the KotlinPoet solution? Maybe in an answer? I guess, what you mean is I should at build time determine whether there are variants for an image file and then generate a function which allows checking whether a resource has variants?

"what you mean is I should at build time determine whether there are variants for an image file and then generate a function which allows checking whether a resource has variants?" -- exactly! You could keep the code generation to building a simple Map, then have an ordinary function to look up values in the Map. That way, if you need to tweak the code generation, you should be able to minimize the number of places in the code that might be affected.

@CommonsWare thanks, that indeed sounds like a great idea.

Following @CommonsWare's suggestion, I ended up with the following code generator, using KotlinPoet.
class NightDrawablesNamesSetGenerator {

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            // list all drawable-night folders
            val nightDrawableFoldersPattern = Regex("^drawable[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*-night[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\$")

            val nightDrawableFolders = File("../app/src/main/res/").listFiles { file, name ->
                file.isDirectory && name.matches(nightDrawableFoldersPattern)
            } ?: emptyArray()

            // list all names of files in the drawable-night folders
            val nightDrawableNames = buildSet {
                nightDrawableFolders.flatMap { it.listFiles()?.toList() ?: emptyList() }
                    .map { it.nameWithoutExtension }
                    .filter { it.isNotBlank() }
                    .forEach { add(it) }
            }

            // define a private property holding the generated set for later generation with KotlinPoet
            val nightDrawableNamesProperty = PropertySpec.builder("nightDrawableNames", typeNameOf<Set<String?>>())
                .addModifiers(KModifier.PRIVATE)
                .initializer("%L", "setOf(" + nightDrawableNames.joinToString(", ") { "\"$it\"" } + ")")
                .build()

            // define a public getter for the property
            val getNightResourceNamesFun = FunSpec.builder("getNightDrawableNames")
                .returns(typeNameOf<Set<String?>>())
                .addStatement("return nightDrawableNames")
                .build()

            // define the file to write to
            val fileSpec = FileSpec.builder("my.app.util", "NightDrawables")
                .addProperty(nightDrawableNamesProperty)
                .addFunction(getNightResourceNamesFun)
                .build()

            // save the generated file - here in the main app folder, but one could also store it in a codegen module, and supply it as part of that module to the app module
            fileSpec.writeTo(File("../app/src/main/java/"))
        }
    }
}

For now, I'm running this from a separate Gradle task. Might convert it to a plugin at some point.
The task lives in a codegen module's build.gradle, where also the generator resides.
tasks.register('generateNightDrawableNamesSetGenerator', JavaExec) {
    inputs.files fileTree(dir: '../app/src/main/res', includes: ['*-night*/**'])
    outputs.file '../app/src/main/java/com/photoroom/util/NightDrawables.kt'

    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = 'com.photoroom.codegen.NightDrawableNamesSetGenerator'
}

The task is run as a dependency for building the app as defined in the app's build.gradle:
preBuild.dependsOn(":codegen:generateNightDrawableNamesSetGenerator")

Then, in the app project, I have a simple extension function to check for existing night variants for any given Drawable resource ID:
fun @receiver:DrawableRes Int.hasNightVariant(context: Context): Boolean = getNightDrawableNames()
    .contains(context.resources.getResourceEntryName(this))

